# Setting random values to unassigned/optional parameters

Tags: java, parameters, optional-parameters

I am building a tiled map generator application and I want users to be able to set subareas of a map to be a specific type of tile when building it.
This is currently implemented like this:

```
public boolean setArea(int bottomLeftX, int bottomLeftY, int subWidth, int subHeight, TerrainType aAreaType){
    boolean areaOverflow = false;
        System.out.println("Subarea coords...     x,y:"+bottomLeftX+","+bottomLeftY+" width/height:"+subWidth+"/"+subHeight);
        for(int x=bottomLeftX;x<=bottomLeftX+subWidth-1;x++){
            for(int y=bottomLeftY;y<=bottomLeftY+subHeight-1;y++){
                if(x>=0 && y>=0 &&
                   x<this.getWidth() && y<this.getHeight()){
                    this.setTile(x, y, aAreaType);
                }
                else{
                    areaOverflow = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return areaOverflow;
    }
}
```

(TerrainType is an enum with information on the terrain type and the setTile method sets a value in the map array to be a certain terrain type. this.getWidth/Height() returns the size of the array for the map)

But I want the user to not have to decide on every value and allow some to be chosen randomly. The idea I had initially was to allow the user to set some values as null and if a value gets passed in as null, have the Java random function decide on an arbitrary value for that parameter (within the size of the map), however you can't set ints to null. I was wondering what an alternative option would involve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your parameters as `Integer`s instead of as `int`s. Then you would have no problems passing in `null` values for them. And inside the method you will be able to check if any of these parameters is `null` or not, and act based on the results of these checks.

Comment: That's great, thanks! But what about selecting a random enum as well as their properties?

Comment: Just as a followup, using Integers worked perfectly and then for the Enum parameter ( @zubergu ), I did this at the start of the method: `if (aAreaType == null) {aAreaType = TerrainType.values()[random.nextInt(TerrainType.values().length)];}`

Answer (score 0):

As Java doesn't have default arguments feature, one approach is to overload the method in a *telescopic* fashion:

```
public class RandomArgumentsSample {

    private final Random generator = new Random();

    public void someMethod(int param1, int param2, SomeEnum someEnum) {
        // Do something useful with all the params, which are never null
    }

    public void someMethod(int param1, int param2) {
        // randomValue() static method implemented in SomeEnum
        // returns one value of the enum, randomly
        this.someMethod(param1, param2, SomeEnum.randomValue());
    }

    public void someMethod(int param1, SomeEnum someEnum) {
        int param2 = this.generator.nextInt(); // change to return number within range
        this.someMethod(param1, param2, someEnum);
    }

    // telescoping overloading is not magic
    // here order of arguments is changed
    // so we don't define a method with the same name and 
    // same argument types in the same order
    public void someMethod(SomeEnum someEnum, int param2) {
        int param1 = this.generator.nextInt(); // change to return number within range
        this.someMethod(param1, param2, someEnum);
    }

    public void someMethod(SomeEnum someEnum) {
        int param1 = this.generator.nextInt(); // change to return number within range
        this.someMethod(param1, someEnum);
        // could have also been this.someMethod(someEnum, param2); 
        // with param2 generated randomly
    }

    // here we choose to generate a default value for param2
    // we can't have another someMethod that receives only one int,
    // since it will clash with this one
    public void someMethod(int param1) {
        int param2 = this.generator.nextInt(); // change to return number within range
        this.someMethod(param1, param2);
    }

    // all arguments are random!
    public void someMethod() {
        int param1 = this.generator.nextInt(); // change to return number within range
        this.someMethod(param1);
    }
}
```

Please read the comments, as they have some explanations.

The idea is that the methods with less parameters call the methods with more parameter and generate default (or random) values for the parameters it doesn't receive. At the end of the chain, the method that receives all parameters and performs the actual task is invoked.

This approach is not perfect, in my example there's no way to have two `someMethod(int)`, i.e. one that receives one `int` as `param1` and another one that receives one `int` as `param2`. But sometimes it's enough, especially if you don't need all possible combinations of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative if changing int to Int is not an option for any reason (so to NULLs).

Overload your method but only with parameters that user has to give explicitly and call the method with full parameters from inside of this methos.

Simplified example:

```
public int myMethod(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a+b+c;
}

public int myMethod(int a) {
  return myMethod(a, (int)Math.random(),(int)Math.random());
}
```

As for the part you asked about randomizing enum, I'd go with adding static method to you enum, called e.g. `randomize()`. If you were asking about specific implementation of this method - that's another story.

Returning `ENUM.values()[someRandomIndex]` is just one from the top of my head.